# Compensating Variation - Interpreting the formulae

Tags: utility, optimization, lagrangian

Assume $U(x,y) = x^{1/2}y^{1/2}$ s.t. $P_xx + P_yy = m$
And a price increase from $P_x$ to $P'_x$:

- $U_0 = \frac{M}{2(P_xP_y)^{1/2}}$
- Compensation variation formulae is: $\frac{M + ∆M}{2(P_x'P_y)^{1/2}} = U_0$
- $∆M = U_02(P'_xP_y)^{1/2} - U_12(P'_xP_y)^{1/2}$

**We can rewrite this as:** $∆M = (U_0 - U_1)2(P'_xP_y)^{1/2} = ∆U[2(P'_xP_y)^{1/2}]$

1. What is a meaningful way to inteparate this?
2. E.g. what is the $2(P'_xP_y)^{1/2}$ coefficient on our $∆U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "interpetation" for these coefficients, any more than there is one for the 2 in $2(P_x'P_y)^{1/2}$.

Both here and in [your other question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54382/compensating-variation-for-u-xy1-2-and-u-xy), the equation $\Delta M = U_02(P'_xP_y)^{1/2} - U_12(P'_xP_y)^{1/2}$ is not particularly useful in itself. The compensanting variation is meant to measure the change in income that would be adequate compensate the consumer for the change in price. It could be considered adequate compensation, because it would enable the consumer to reach their pre price change utility level, i.e. $U_0 = U_1$. You should definitely use this piece of information.

Using the above and your formula $U_0 = \frac{M}{2(P_xP_y)^{1/2}}$, you can calculate $\Delta M$ as a function of the other parameters. That's it, that shows you how much additional income would compensate the consumer for the price change, given their utility function and all other parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Giskard, and for reading my other post! 1) Are my calculations in the other post correct, particularly for $U = xy$? 2) is there any reason that $∆M$ would be proportional to the $∆U$ by the amount of the coefficient? 

I ask, only because for example for the Income effect $-\frac{∆M}{2P'_x}$ appears to have a meaningful economic interpretation. We divide the income change by 2, because the value of the goods are weighted equally, and then we divide this remaining income by $P'_x$ to see how many  $x's$ we could buy at the new price. It's minus as $P_x$ increases.

Comment: As in that's an example of a seemingly abstract formulae having some meaning. If you think there's nothing to it, I won't insist anymore, thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is anything to it, the pattern becomes unwound/more complicated if you use a non-symmetric Cobb-Douglas function.

Comment: Okay, thank you @Giskard!

Comment: If you do get chance to confirm the calculation on the other question, that'd be great. No worries if not!